Is it possible to retrive job application list of a user using Linkedin API?
I know we can access user profile, name, email using LinkedIn OAuth token. But I'm curious about knowing whether we can access the applied jobs data of a linkedin user through API's.
Feel free to answer, If you have worked on this previously, please write your answers.
I tried exploring linkedin OAuth token, and I got user info such as name, email, profile.
I'm expecting the user applied job data.
